# Google Play subscriptions always "Pending payment"

Tags: android, google-play, subscriptions, developer-console, in-app-subscription

I'm having problems to understand why almost all (90 %) of my active subscriptions in the Google Play Developer Console are in "Pending payment" status, despite the subscriptions are out of trial and grace periods and the status of the subscription is "Active".

I tried myself to pay for the subscriptions and all worked well.

Does anyone know what can cause this? Any hint is welcomed.

Comment: do you have any updates?

Comment: Same thing happening to me

Comment: Any info on this? Why does this happen?

Comment: Any update on this query?

Comment: Any updates on this issue? @Vishal16

Comment: Did you find solution for this?
@NamanyayGoel

Comment: @Yupi Nope, very annoying :/ What kind of app are you making, send me a message info on profile?

Comment: Do you have and update?